# Problem running 32 bit app in Win7 x64

Tags: windows

Original link: http://wattsupwiththat.com/2011/02/21/windows-7-64-bit-now-even-suckier/

Basically, he can't get his 32 bit app to run under x64. He has tried XP compat mode.

Is there any alternative besides buyint the very expensive x64 version?

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic. Have the OP post his own question on SU if he really needs help.

Answer (score 5):

My experience with x64 compatibility issues generally boils down to one thing: a bug in .Net software compiled in the "Any CPU" mode that pulls in a 32-bit unmanaged dll.

When running on x64 systems, the .Net framework doesn't yet have the information it needs at app startup time to know that a *dynamically* loaded library needs 32bit mode, and so it starts up "Any CPU"-compiled programs with a 64bit process. This is what it should do. Of course, this 64bit process cannot later load a 32bit dll. It's about a 10 second fix on the part of the software developer to change the app over from "Any CPU" to "x86" and then rebuild, but you have to convince them that they need to do that.

This is actually a very common scenario, as a lot of apps these days (especially in categories like video processing that provide a front-end for cpu intensive tasks) will use .Net to build a windows interface that just calls out to a more-performant library written in C or C++.

I remember a discussion (possibly among MS MVP's) about potentially changing the default compile mode in Visual Studio from "Any CPU" to "x86" to address this issue, but I don't remember what ever came of it.

Comment: You're making a massive assumption that this software is incompatible due to a .NET problem. -1 for you.

Comment: +1 Regardless of the assumptions about the original problem, this answer makes a point worth noting, and may explain a pending issue I have with a .NET application after moving everything from 32-bit XP to 64-bit Win7 recently....

Comment: @Randolph, given you know no more about the software than Joel, what puts you in the position to presume the answer is wrong?!

Comment: @Randolph - I think you're being unfair to Joel - he's not saying the OP's problem must be down to .net, he's instead saying "My experiences are..." - sharing one's own experiences of when you have seen an issue is not the same as assuming that everyone else is having the same problem you are.

Comment: Given that the original article states that there is a specific version for a 64-bit platform that the complainant is not willing to upgrade to, I'm disinclined to change my opinion.

Comment: I have reversed my downvote.